# Magento1 invoice email: ordered items not visible

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, email-templates

The invoice-email doesn't show the ordered items table. My template contains this code:

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

However, this part is missing in the email. I tried to find the code that should generate the HTML, I think sales.xml tells me to look at the "email/order/invoice/items.phtml"-template file. But changing its content doesn't seem to have any effect.

Where should I start to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Next you can look into below files:

1. /app/design/frontend/***YOUR_THEME ***/layout/sales.xml

   ```
   <sales_email_order_invoice_items>

    /********Check if somehow this section got modified***********/   

    </sales_email_order_invoice_items>
   ```
2. /app/design/frontend/***YOUR_THEME ***/template/email/order/invoice/items.phtml

Check if this file is modified by any module. If yes try using core files. Hope this will work.

Comment: I have checked that's code..same as core code..but not working.